# Getting error if trying to download my standalone app: Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, download

[image]

- I use VS 2010 C# Express
- The file is digitally signed (signed/verified with signtool)
- Target framework: .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
- .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is installed
- I'm uploading the exe to a simple static html page
- If I (or anyone) click on the download link get the message above
- Right-click -> Save Target As... works OK
- I can run the file without issues after downloading

Comment: I am not sure about these 2 points -- I'm uploading the exe to a simple static html page , I can run the file without issues after downloading

Comment: What is the issue? I make the app available on an internal webpage for the users. And if I download it I don't get. Net error.

Comment: Does the project include any non-.Net dll's? Maybe something written in C++? If so, maybe it's the C++ runtime it's talking about.

Comment: Pure c#, no dll included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask why you are targeting .NET 4.0 Client Platform specifically?  Why not go ahead and target to one of the 4.5 versions?  Is there a requirement to target a [discontinued release of .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Within that link and [this one under the 'Additional Information' section](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653), there are statements that indicate an 'in place update' to .NET 4.0 is made to migrate an already installed .NET 4.0 Client Platform to the .NET 4.0 Full Install -- there doesn't appear to be anything written to indicate that 4.0 gets installed by the 4.5 installer, if it's not already installed on the system.

Therefore, all machines with .NET 4.5 installed would have replaced the mentioned 'target framework' of .NET that you're building with something that no longer exists on those machines ... which I believe might account for the popup error received.  Can you, at least, try to target one of the 4.5 versions of .NET and update the executable to download on your server?  Try again and see if the error goes away?  If it does, then the problem that you are facing pertains to .NET Client Platform not (or longer due to 4.5 update) being installed on the client machines.

If that's the case and .NET 4.0 needs to be targeted, then you might need to target the Full 4.0 version instead of the Client Profile version.  Or just move to one of the 4.5 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd venture to guess that the problem is not within the executable itself but somewhere in the delivery of it into the web page or in the delivery of it back down to the end user; especially considering the program will run without issue once it's downloaded.

Have you completely vetted that process?  You mention 'simple static html page' - elaborate on that a bit and you might get more suggestions that will lead you toward a proper solution.  Web server used?  Technology involved?  Personal machine running apache or the like?  or some website generator?  or something like Wordpress?  or some other web hosting company and their products?  If the problem lies therein, then further details would be nice to have to help you deduce what is causing issue.

As I'm sure you're aware, that particular error message appears to be presented mostly to products that utilize products created with or included libraries requiring .NET 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5 - since they are (by default) no longer [pre-installed on newer systems released with Windows 8+](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/net-framework-windows-8) ... a simple test to rule out the possibility would be to simply install the .NET 3.5 installer and see if the problem magically goes away - if it does, then you may need to do a bit of further research on the 'delivery mechanism' - read, web server used - technology it requires - etc ...

If that's way off ... perhaps this is an x86 vs x64 problem?  32bit app running on 64bit OS?  something along those lines?  A simple test would be to create 2 executables: one that is configured to build all output as x86 and one to build all output as x64 - see if both behave the same or if there is a difference, and move forward from there.

I believe that in this situation, you will need to play around and run a few tests before getting to the bottom of it.  Good luck to you.

Comment: What I meant by simple static html page: XAMPP running on a server 2008 r2. The content of the html file: `<html><body><a href="myFile.exe">download</a></body></html>`. That's the delivery mechanism. It requires .NET 4, wich is installed on every single machine which from we tried to download the file. x86 vs x64 issue: As I can run the file on both this shouldn't be an issue, but to make sure I tried. The same appears. For me this seems to be some assembly info or manifest issue, but not sure.

Comment: Have you tried setting the supportedRuntime tag to the application config file to the version of the .Net Framework installed in the system.

    <configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
    </startup>
    </configuration>

Comment: Another thing mentioned ... '.NET Framework 4 Client Profile is installed'  
Is it installed on the Server and Client machines?  or just one or the other?  Is there a specific reason for going with the Client Profile instead of Full?  To note, [in 4.5 the Client Profile has been discontinued](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx).  Something else to consider ..

Comment: It also might be useful to run through this [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool User's Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) on the 2008 R2 Server.

Comment: Bret I really appreciate your efforts, though I tried literally everything you've mentioned so far.

Comment: Have you attempted this in any other browser, aside from IE (chrome, firefox, etc)?  If so, same results?  If other browsers work, then there must be something specific to IE that is causing the problem.

What OS are you (and the any others) running - on the systems used to download the file?  What version of IE is installed?  Are there any add-ons/extensions that might be interfering with the download?  What versions of .NET are installed on the systems used?  Perhaps there is something within these details that helps us find a solution.

Comment: I tried it on google chrome, but there is no pop-up for 'save or run' for any file. Machines running Windwos OS (Vista 32, 7 32/64, 8 64, 8.1 64, Server 2008 /R2 64). IE verions are randomly 7/8/9/10/11(?). All the machines have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: Added new answer because my response was too long for a comment ... and thought it would make more sense to keep the timeline correct instead of modifying my answer above.

Comment: Tried with "full" .Net 4 and 4.5 as well, no go.

Comment: Then perhaps it is not your application that requires an earlier version of .NET to be installed?  Maybe there is some mechanism within IE that requires some earlier version ... a simple check to make; install the other versions (e.g. 3.5 and 4.0 full) onto one of the client machines attempting the download.  If the problem goes away ...

Comment: The server doesn't matter. It's a html script which runs on the client side.

Comment: Perhaps another approach altogether ... take your specific .exe out of the equation.  Replace it with some other setup.exe (7zip or something) file.  Modify your html to whatever the new filename is and try again - if you still have the same problem across several different client machines, then you might need to take that up Microsoft ... as, at that point, the problem would no longer pertain to your code, executable, targeted .NET, etc ... it would pertain to iexplore.exe and its 'run downloaded file' mechanism.  Let me know what the outcome is after trying a different file in the html.

Comment: I did that. But if consider that we download dozens of files on a daily basis from other sites and can't see this issue, then I think it's not a good guess.

Comment: Perhaps, then, it's time to upgrade to [VS 2013 express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)?  If your code builds on 2010, then there shouldn't be a big migration effort.  To go along with that, it might be time to dissect your app.config file (as you mentioned earlier, there might be something there) for potential clashing issues - would advise to go through it line by line and verify everything that is included should be there - and for things that you are uncertain about, research them thoroughly to ensure they aren't causing problems inadvertently.